# SQL Server Insert values from one table to another, and increment a column value while doing so

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables in my database. Table T1 contains merchandise information, like Name, PIN, manufacturer and so on. 
Table T2 is like an entity table that needs to be updated sometimes, so I need to write a script for its update.

What I'm doing is selecting all entities from T1, who's ID is not in T2 and making a new table from it.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
  IdMerc INT
  Code Varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (IdMerc, Code)
SELECT [IdMerchandise], CONCAT([manufact],'.',[city])
FROM T1
WHERE T1 NOT IN (SELECT [IdMerchandise] 
                 JOIN T1 ON [IdMerchandise]=[IdEnt]
                 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

Now, I need to insert values from #TEMP to T2, but T2 has this `[IdEnt]` column that needs to be an incremental value. My T2 already has a primary key `[RowId]`

My question is, how do I insert all data from #TEMP to T2, but with incrementing the [IdEnt] column while inserting? I already tried Insert-Select with incrementing the IdEnt but it throws an error that says I can't add an increment statement to select and insert.

Comment: i think your problem is not clear.what is the sample data in #TEMP.I don't see any [IdEnt] .Now what output are you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here:

1. [Identity column on T2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)
2. [Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)
3. [Row number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186734(v=sql.110).aspx) while inserting into #TEMP

Please read the above and state what do you exactly need in your destination table - just unique integers or values that will follow some pattern? Then I can provide you suitable code.

Comment: I only need values that follow a pattern. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: So select MAX(ID) from your destination table and add ROW_NUMBER to it while inserting data. You can either do it while inserting into #TEMP or T2. Do you need help with the code?

Comment: Well I just need to know how can I save the MAX(ID) and use it in identity function. That will solve all my problems.

Comment: You just need it once while creating the identity column, then it will do the whole job itself (it remembers the last value and inserts the next one automatically). So your seed will be MAX(ID) + 1 and increment 1. After you set up identity function you do insert anything into this column while inserting your data (as if you would like to leave it as NULL) and SQL server will take care of the rest.

Comment: I can't use variables in identity function. That is the problem. I cant set the variable as a seed .

Comment: Just hard code it. You will only do this once. Normally you create identity function while creating a table, if there is data in the table already (as it is in your case) you need to know the max value. The variable I talked about earlier should be used while approaching this issue with ROW_NUMBER solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`IDENTITY` *function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql). This is not the same as an IDENTITY property on a column. The IDENTITY function can generate the Id you need during the INSERT. Note that you still need to know where the Ids start (ie. the seed).

You can achieve the same using a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and offset it with a seed.